# Allow fields but without obligation in firebase rules and validation

Tags: validation, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I would like to know how can I only allow certain new fields in an existing or new object but **without obligation** to have ALL of this fields always.

For example i would like to validate a **product object**
I allow fields like name, size, price, height, width and no other not listed field but at the same time objects are valid which would have only some of this fields.

```
".validate": "newData.hasChildren(['name', 'size','price', 'height', 'width',])"
```

All fields are obligated I think. So a new product without height or width would be invalid. But I would like they are still valid but not allow somebody invent new fields which are not listed at all.

This need to work also with existing and new products. 
Thanks in advance for your tips.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To only allow the fields you want, use a [wildcard location](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/security/database/#location) (a rule that starts with a $). This will match any path you have **not** already specified.

From the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/securing-data#using_variables_to_capture_path_segments)...

> The dynamic $ variables can also be used in parallel with constant
>   path names. In this example, we're using the $other variable to
>   declare a .validate rule that ensures that widget has no children
>   other than title and color. Any write that would result in additional
>   children being created would fail.
>
> ```
> {
>   "rules": {
>     "widget": {
>       // a widget can have a title or color attribute
>       "title": { ".validate": true },
>       "color": { ".validate": true },
>
>       // but no other child paths are allowed
>       // in this case, $other means any key excluding "title" and "color"
>       "$other": { ".validate": false }
>     }
>   }
> }
> ```

As for removing the obligation for all rules to be matched, you can do waht they do in the example above. You also might be able to use [OR](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/security/database/#or) as part of your validate rules:

```
".validate": "newData.hasChild('name') || newData.hasChild('size') || newData.hasChild('price')"
```

Comment: thank you for your detailed information. This mean I an use ""$other": { ".validate": false }" basically in all of my objects and children to prevent anybody create new children which are not named already. I like also the alternative version for certain situations. I think I can setup all with your help now. Made it much clearer for me...

Comment: Awesome @Oliver! And if the info solves the rules issue for you, please mark as the solution.